# How to get the current view of my UWP app from background thread?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

In my UWP app, when a post call succeeds, I need to show a notification to the user. This notification has to be shown in the current window in which the user is. I will get to know the success of the post call in the background thread only. So once I receive the success code from server, I need to identify which is the current window and I have to display a notification to the user in that window.

`Window.Current` gives me null when accessed from background thread.

If I try to access `Window.Current` within the `CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync` it gives me the main window.

If I try to access `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().CoreWindow.Dispatcher`from the background thread `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView()` throws the below exception

```
Exception = {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element not found.

    Element not found.

    at Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView()
```

I did a small round of analysis to find out what is happening with the below code snippet.

```
        foreach (var iteratingview in CoreApplication.Views)
        {
            iteratingview.Dispatcher.RunOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                int id = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
                bool main = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().IsMain;
                bool isMain = iteratingview.IsMain;
            });
        }
```

The boolean value `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().IsMain` gives me `true` when the `iteratingview` is main view and `false` when the `iteratingview` is a secondary view, which means `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView()` returns me the view inside which dispatcher I'm calling it. `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()` also behaves in the same way.

But my requirement is to identify which is the current window/view where the user is.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is there any other way to get the current window's dispatcher from the background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to decouple the two and use an event from your background thread. This way, any foreground window(s) that want to display information can subscribe to the event, and the background thread doesn't need to know anything about which one is active etc. and also won't have to worry about which thread to dispatch the call into (the window(s) that subscribe to the event can trivially do the dispatching themselves with their own `Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are no straightforward way to know that which window(view) is the focused one, from the outside - background thread.
But, each window(view) can know it by `Window.Current.CoreWindow.Activated` event. In my case, I had implemented the dirty code to set/clear the flag that shows "I'm activated / deactivated!" within the window(view), and checked it from the outside. This way worked well.